# How to run tests only for a single Maven module?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Given a Maven project with modules `dad` and `son`, where `son` depends on `dad`, `mvn -am -pl son test` runs the tests for `dad` too. Is there a way to avoid this and only run tests for `son` module?

Note that there a couple of ways to achieve this, though each has its own caveats which I don't prefer:

- Using `-Dtest="**/son/*Test.java" -DfailIfNoTests=false` overrides the `maven-surefire-plugin` config in the module.
- Similar to `-Dtest`, JUnit 5 tags could also be filtered, but this approach suffers from the same shortcoming aforementioned.
- One can first do an `install -DskipTests=true` and then `mvn -pl son test`, though this pollutes the local Maven repository with partial work.

Comment: Initial `mvn install` for `dad` is the idiomatic way with Maven for this type of work. Though you also have an option to run them from IDE :)

Comment: So you want to __compile__  "dad"'s classes but you don't want to run its tests, right?

Comment: What about simply not using the `-am` cause it says: `If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list`...... Why do you do such things on command line and not within your ide?  Apart from that what is so problematic to use the `install .. ` and `mvn -pl son test` approach? So your local repository can be cleaned up easy? ...Running tests from a module or parts of it ... just using the IDE ... never doing that on command line ... the CI runs all tests on my branches...

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Polluting `~/.m2` with partial work just to run the tests of a single module doesn't sound *idiomatic* to me.

Comment: @MarkBramnik, right. To be honest, I don't even want to compile `dad`, though if you don't provide `-am` to compile the dependency modules, Maven complains that `dad` is not found.

Comment: The `$HOME/.m2/repository` is a cache nothing else... polluting? There are then SNAPSHOT's etc.. So what?

Comment: @VolkanYazıcı, it's local repo, it doesn't matter what you have here. It exists to be polluted since it may contain SNAPSHOTs.

Comment: Yes of course cause it's a dependency...than you have to go the way `mvn install` for the whole project. Than you can use `mvn -pl son` from the root which will resolve the dependency from your local cache...

Comment: The cache is on your local machine which you can delete any time if it becomes to large ... then everything will be downloaded again... except we are talking about a setup for a CI solution like Jenkins ... I suppose we are talking about local development on dev machine...

Comment: Regarding running from the IDE... IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.5 cannot run tests for `log4j-layout-template-json` module due to its complex setup. Hence, it is not an option always. Thanks for your kind *alternative* work arounds, though in the question I explicitly stated that I want to avoid `install` and want to do this using `mvn`, not an IDE.

Comment: @VolkanYazıcı I guess it is good to have alternative approaches because the thing you asked for is probably not really possible.

Comment: If you can't run your tests from your IDE then the tests are too complex or wrongly done...and must be simplified/changed...Furthermore that is an indication to run such tests on a CI solution like Jenkins...   Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade your IDE ... 2020.2 (2020.3 is around the corner already in beta)... Do not use old Software...The test sounds more like an integration tests ? Complex setup? What is the real problem here? Because you are insistence on not to use `install` but you do ???

Comment: @JFabianMeier, sadly, I think so. Just wanted to double-check before creating a Maven ticket.

Answer (score 5):

On maven 3.3.9, I ran:

`mvn test -pl :web-module`

to ran the web module. In the POM, should look like this, `<module>web-module</module>`, inside the `modules` tag.

To test a specific class inside that module:

`mvn test -pl :web-module -Dtest="ClassUnderTest"`

Answer (score 1):

I am stuck on this for a while, but eventually, I got the solution.

This is my condition:

- I have many submodules: A, B, and C.  some of them are independent, and some of them are dependent.
- I want to only run the Module-C test, but C dependence on A and B.
- `mvn clean test -pl C`  does not work for me, because of 2.
- `mvn clean test -pl C -am`  work for me, but it runs all of the module tests.

This is my thought:

the reason why `mvn clean test -pl C -am` run all tests, is because C has a dependence on A and B, So module C must compile A and B first, and then compile C.

These is the Resolutions:

1. make parent Pom skip all of the module tests.
2. make a profile on Module C, and enable the test.
3. just run  `mvn clean test -DmoduleCTest=true`

The module C pom is like this, and another module is the same way but has diff profile id.

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>moduleCTest</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>moduleCTest</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```